# Prolog- which free software can I use for Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have never used Prolog before. I wanted to know which Open Source Software can I use for Prolog.

Thanks a lot
Cindy

Comment: Not only is this off-topic, but did you even try to type your question into a search engine?

Comment: Please always read the info on the tag [tag:prolog] first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWI-Prolog is a great one! It can be downloaded from here: http://www.swi-prolog.org/download/stable

Comment: Yes, it is an open-source, liberal license, modern Prolog. It comes with a lot of great libraries ("batteries included") unlike for example GNU-Prolog.

Comment: @CindyLee you should mark it as the accepted answer.